# Lua and fake Typecast

Tags: c++, casting, lua

I'm working with Lua and C++ (using LuaWrapper) and I'm having trouble with something. Let's say I have these classes:

```
class Bar{...};
class Foo
{
    ...
    std::map<std::string,Bar*> _barlist;
    ...
    Bar* getBar(std::string key)
    {
        return _barlist[key];
    }
}

class BarDerived1 : public Bar{...}
class BarDerived2 : public Bar{...}
```

I have access to `Foo` and `Foo::getBar()` from Lua , the thing is that the type from the object returned is `Bar` and I don't have access to its `BarDerivedX` methods.

As I understand it, Objects/Classes in Lua are simply MetaTables with functions assigned to keys, so I was wondering if there's a way to copy these extra functions from the `BarDerivedX` class to the `Bar` object (and would that even work?), also, is this the best way to do it or should I cast it in C++ before letting Lua access it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The purpose of polymorphism, in any language, is to not have to care exactly what type something is. If you give someone, whether Lua or C++, a `Bar` object, then `Bar` should have the interfaces that the people need to do whatever they need to do.

That's the purpose of virtual functions. A virtual function defined in `Bar` can be overridden with a different behavior in `BarDerived1`. Other code doesn't have to know that they are being handed a derived class; they can just take a `Bar` like always.

There are generally only two reasons to make a class derived from another. The first is polymorphism: you want to specialize a class by altering the behavior of certain functions.

The other reason is to gain access to its implementation. For example, if you're making a Unicode string, you could use a std::basic_string to store the encoded data. You could then *privately* derive from std::basic_string, thus allowing you to gain the storage optimizations that std::basic_string has, but you provide a different interface (since private inheritance doesn't allow the outside world to know that you derived from it).

If you want everyone to use `Bar` objects that can have different behaviors based on derived classes, then you should be using virtual functions and polymorphism. However, if you are *changing* the interface in derived classes, then that's probably a sign of a design problem. Maybe those derived classes shouldn't be derived classes at all. Maybe they should be entirely separate classes that a `Bar` instance may or may not have, based on some initialization parameters.

It's hard to say more without specifics on what you're actually doing. But in general, if you're using inheritance-based polymorphism correctly, you shouldn't need to cast from a `Bar` to more derived versions. Just use the `Bar` interface.

Comment: I see your point, but what I'm doing is not object oriented programming, I'm studying Entities and Components, the `Foo` class is an Entity and the `Bar` class is a generic component, different components have different behaviors and different interfaces, but I also want to keep them accessible through the same map, so they are all derived from the same base class... when I have to call a derived function I just cast the right type.

Comment: @Luke, how is what you do **not** object oriented?!

Comment: @Luke: What you are describing is an _abuse_ of inheritance. The purpose of inheritance is to define a relationship between two classes. It is not so that you can store two unrelated items in the same list and do a `dynamic_cast` to figure out which one you have. If you find yourself doing that, then what you need is a `boost::variant`. What reason do you have for keeping these two unrelated classes in the same list?

Comment: I don't know, easy access to them? So I don't have to declare a member of each BarDerived inside the Foo class... that's how I've always done, same base class and typecasting, if that's the wrong way to do it what's the alternative?

Comment: If you want to use a entity/component system I suggest you do about it differently. Have an entity 'class', but the entity is actually just an unsigned integer. Then, each component type has a "RegisterEntity" func. Each type of component has a hashtable where the objects are stored, with the key being the entity's ID. When you want to get the PhysicsComponent for the Entity, what you actually do then is pass the entity Id into the PhysicsComponent hashtable and get the component you want. You can probably refactor some of that code into a common Component class, but it's not needed.

Comment: And how are components going to talk to each other if not by having a common object? Sending messages is too slow and much more complicated than just having a pointer and going through it to access other components

Comment: If you have the entity id handy, you can easily get a pointer to any one of it's components from it's hashtable and do whatever you want to it. There's a number of ways to handle inter-component communication, but it's not really a discussion well suited for the comments section here, I suggest looking at some of the questions and answers on gamedev.stackexchange.com (there's plenty there on Entity/Component architecture), or asking some of your own if something isn't clear.

Answer (score 2):

There is a basic principle in class inheritance:

> It must be possible to interchange an instance of the superclass by an instance of any of its subclasses.

If B is a subclass of A, then in any places where you use an instance of A, you should be able to use an instance of B.

If your code isn't doing that - then simply you are not using inheritance correctly. Definitively, you are not using it correctly if the only reason you need a subclass is to make is simpler to create a collection.

As others are saying, a proper solution is to use a "generic type" on the collection declaration; Remove `Bar` completely, and in the collection declaration, use `boost::variant`, null pointers or the equivalent in your toolset.